# Sitecore LDAP Module Compatibility

Tags: module

I have a Sitecore 6.4 website that has Sitecore LDAP Module "LightLDAP.dll", This website needs to be upgraded to Sitecore 8.2, My question is: Is the Sitecore LDAP Module compatible with Sitecore 8.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the LightLDAP you have is likely not compatible. You'll need to make sure you upgrade your module to version 1.3 which is compatible with Sitecore 8.2. It can be downloaded here:

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Active_Directory/1_3/Active_Directory_1_3.aspx